# What does this vhdl code do?We have understood that it is used for up and down counting. But we are not understanding the technicalities

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Arith.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Unsigned.ALL;


Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;


entity freq_div is
    Port (clk_p, clk_n , rst, up, pause : in  STD_LOGIC;
           count : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0));
end freq_div;

architecture Behavioral of freq_div is

signal clk2: std_logic;
signal cnt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
signal clk: std_logic_vector(28 downto 0):=(others=>'0');


COMPONENT ila_1

PORT (  clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    probe0 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT  ;

 begin

   IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
  generic map (
     DIFF_TERM => FALSE, -- Differential Termination 
     IBUF_LOW_PWR => TRUE, -- Low power (TRUE) vs. performance (FALSE) setting for referenced I/O standards
     IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
  port map (
     O => clk2,  -- Buffer output
     I => clk_p,  -- Diff_p buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
     IB => clk_n -- Diff_n buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
  );



    process(clk2, rst)
        begin
            if (rst = '1')then
                clk <= (others=>'0');
            elsif (clk2'event and clk2 = '1')then
                clk <= clk + 1;
            end if;
    end process;


    process(clk(25), rst,up,pause) 
        begin
        if (rst = '1') then
            cnt <= (others=>'0');
        elsif (clk(25) = '1' and clk(25)'event) then
            if (up = '1' and pause = '0')then
                cnt <= cnt + '1';
            elsif (up = '0' and pause = '0') then
                cnt <= cnt - '1';
            elsif( pause ='1')then
                cnt <= cnt;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    count <= cnt;


    U1 : ila_1   PORT MAP (   clk => clk2 ,      probe0 => cnt    );



end Behavioral;
```

We are using zynq board(zc702). In the zynq board we have two clocks: a positive clock(clk_p) and the negative clock(clk_n)....I can see mentioning of these two clocks as in std_logic, but am not getting how they have used these clocks in the program...ie How have they  integrated these two clocks in the program?

Also what is clk(25)?

Also please mention working of the code. We have understood that the code is used for up and down counting.We are not understanding the following part:

```
architecture Behavioral of freq_div is
signal clk2: std_logic;
signal cnt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
signal clk: std_logic_vector(28 downto 0):=(others=>'0');


COMPONENT ila_1

PORT (  clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    probe0 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT  ;

 begin

   IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
  generic map (
     DIFF_TERM => FALSE, -- Differential Termination 
     IBUF_LOW_PWR => TRUE, -- Low power (TRUE) vs. performance (FALSE) setting for referenced I/O standards
     IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
  port map (
     O => clk2,  -- Buffer output
     I => clk_p,  -- Diff_p buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
     IB => clk_n -- Diff_n buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

VHDL is always describing a hardware circuit. First look at the declared data types, with particular attention to the signal width. Next find any sub-modules that have been instantiated, and read each process. (I normally use Verilog instead of VHDL, so I can't vouch for whether this is valid VHDL code or not. But I can recognize enough of the general structure to see how the code is intended to work.) It can help to draw the signal flow from input to output. Especially if you come from a C programming background, it can be easy to lose track of the fact that this is really more of a hardware schematic than a software program.

Input ports are `clk_p` and `clk_n` (differential clock), `rst` (reset), `up` and `pause` (controls for the up/down counter). Output port is `count`.

`clk2` is an internal one-bit signal wire.

`clk` is an internal 29-bit register which is used as a counter, clocked by clk2.

`cnt` is a 4-bit register, which is used by the up/down counter.

The instance `IBUFDS_inst` is converting the differential clock pair `clk_p` and `clk_n` into `clk2`. This is most likely an input buffer specific to the Zynq SoC. Most FPGA's have device-specific input/output/clock buffer primitive units similar to this.

The `process(clk2,rst)` describes a counter that simply increments the value of `clk` on every tick of `clk2`. Note that each bit of `clk` acts like a divide-by-2 of the preceeding bit, so `clk(0)` runs at half of the `clk_p` rate, `clk(1)` runs at 1/4 of `clk_p`, `clk(2)` runs at 1/8 of `clk_p`, etc. This is a common way of implementing a **prescaler**, to slow down a fast clock. `clk(25)` is just one of the slower stages of the `clk` counter.

The `process(clk(25), rst, up, pause)` describes the actual up/down counter. There's no surprises here. The counter has a reset command, an up/down direction select, and a run/pause command. Note that every execution path has a blocking assignment `cnt <= *expression*`. For successful synthesis, it is essential to follow code patterns that the synthesis tool can recognize.

Answer (score 0):

The IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS is pulling in a differential to single ended clock buffer. It takes the clk_n and clk_p and generates a clock signal clk2

The first process then uses this clock signal to increase a 29 bit counter called clk

The second process uses the 26th bit of this counter as it's clock and counts either up or down depending upon the state of the up and pause signals.

The final output is a 4 bit counter running at the input clock divided by 2^27